# How to add autoplay and a loop to a Youtube video on HTML?

Tags: html, youtube, autoplay

I'm having trouble with adding autoplay to the video I want to put on my HTML site. Adding ?autoplay=1 or &autoplay=1 didn't work. -- same with the loop

```
<div class="videoContainer">
    <iframe class="videoContainer__video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HWl8XAOQnTg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You can no longer autoplay videos with audio in Chrome or Safari. The only way to make this work would be to mute the audio by adding `&mute=1` to the URL. http://jsfiddle.net/vrs2b5yL/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello my friend you can find the correct steps to embed a youtube video correctly;

1. On a computer, go to the YouTube video that you want to embed.
2. Under the video, click Share .
3. Click Embed.
4. From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
5. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.

To allow your video to auto play use this `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HWl8XAOQnTg?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1&mute=1"` as well as having `allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"` in your code. Use the steps above to embed your video through youtube first and then add the `autoplay=1` to your video url.

I know you have said you have tried to add `autoplay=1` already but it may help you to retry following my steps. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you! It worked out very well. Didn't know Youtube scrapped the "autoplay with audio idea". Other than the video being mute (no issue with that). I love the outcome!

Comment: @SlappeIk It has nothing to do with YouTube. It is the browser vendors that have implemented the restrictions.

Comment: @SlappeIk No problem mate but yes Turnips comment is correct it is the Browsers idea, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

Not relying on parameters that don't seem to work for me – working workaround for September 2018 (bonus: set width and height by CSS for `#yt-wrap` instead of hard-coding it in JS):

```
<div id="yt-wrap">
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>
</div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    player.mute(); // comment out if you don't want the auto played video muted
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(0);
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Update from`function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {...}` to `window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function(){...}`

Comment: Don't have anywhere to test right now. Can anyone else confirm this works? I'll update the answer then.

Comment: Code above https://jsfiddle.net/x45ur3kd/1/, vs https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Autoplays and loops on mute, works for phones and all browsers in 2022. Not all my code just different bits I pirated from other smart people. Just put in your own video id

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div class="iframe-container">
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>
<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'YOgtEDP5mlE',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1, 'rel': 0, 'loop': 1, 'autopause': 0 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
'onStateChange':onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
   event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      player.seekTo(0);
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
/* Make the youtube video responsive */
  .iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
  }
  .iframe-container iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here use this: 
**OPEN THE BELOW CODE PEN LINK**
It will loop your video too : *(Runs the cached version of video, look upon @Turnip Comment)*

> ***;&autoplay=1;&loop=1;&playlist=HWl8XAOQnTg***

https://codepen.io/GAUTAMRAJU15/pen/MqLJRa

```html
<iframe class="videoContainer__video" width="560" height="315"     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HWl8XAOQnTg?rel=0&amp;&amp;showinfo=0;&autoplay=1;&loop=1;&playlist=HWl8XAOQnTg"> </iframe>
```

Comment: This is incorrect this is not the code the OP desires as this will not autoplay. The reason it is auto playing for you is because its working like a cache.

Comment: @connorg98 can you explain this cache thing ?

Comment: Sure!! So you cant really autoplay video's anymore and i am not too sure about the reason for this, however because you have created your html autoplay in a codepen and you have already opened the video on the codepen before, your browser remembers this so it will only autoplay for you. If someone else comes to your codepen and presses play, 9 times out of 10 it will autoplay for them every time they refresh.

Comment: oh i got it , this is due to Turbolinks caching. Even though the auto-video is not visible, it is stored in the cache, and therefore will still play automatically.

Comment: Yeah you get it :)